# Error de división entre cero

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, visual-studio, windows-forms

Buenas tardes tengo este error, me dice que hay un error de `división entre cero`, este es el query que me arroja ese error

```
Select Count(fechavisitaadd) As planeadosvisita
     , Count(riesgoalto) As vriesgoalto
     , Convert(Decimal(10, 1), Convert(Decimal(10, 1), Count(riesgoalto)) / Count(fechavisitaadd) * 100) As vpromalto 
       --, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), COUNT(RIESGOALTO)) / COUNT(fechaVisitaADD) * 100)) AS VPROMALTO

     , Count(riesgomedio) As vriesgomedio
     , Convert(Decimal(10, 1), Convert(Decimal(10, 1), Count(riesgomedio)) / Count(fechavisitaadd) * 100) As vprommedio
       --, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), COUNT(RIESGOMEDIO)) / COUNT(fechaVisitaADD) * 100)) AS VPROMMEDIO

     , Count(fechavisitaadd) - (Count(riesgoalto) + Count(riesgomedio)) As vriesgobajo
     , Convert(Decimal(10, 1), Convert(Decimal(10, 1), Count(fechavisitaadd) - (Count(riesgoalto) + Count(riesgomedio))) / Count(fechavisitaadd) * 100) As vprombajo
--, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), (COUNT(fechaVisitaADD) - (COUNT(RIESGOALTO) + COUNT(RIESGOMEDIO)))) / (PLANEADOSVISITA) * 100)) AS VPROMBAJO
       From (
              Select empresa_sap
                   , idempresa_sap
                   , fechavisitaadd
                   , fechavishallazgoadd
                   , Case resultvisitaadd
                         When 0 Then 'RA'
                     End As riesgoalto
                   , Case resultvisitaadd
                         When 13 Then 'RM'
                     End As riesgomedio
              --  ,CASE
              --                        WHEN fechaVisitaADD IS NOT NULL AND resultVisitaADD IS NULL THEN 'RB'
              --END AS RIESGOBAJO
                     From sintesiscumplimiento.dbo.sintesisinfo As sc
                     --WHERE YEAR(fecha_ingreso) < @anio
                     --AND MONTH(fecha_ingreso) = @mes
                     --AND estatus = 1
                     Where fechavisitaadd Is Not Null And mesvisitaadd = @Mes And familia Is Null
            ) As visitaadd;
```

Este error al parecer viene desde el campo `fechaVisitaADD` pero no estoy muy seguro, ya que es el único dato que esta dividiendo.

No se si podrían ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Matemáticamente, la división entre 0 no es posible, ni correcta e irreproducible. Esto se ve reflejado en las operaciones matemáticas en programación, si intentas dividir entre 0 en CUALQUIER lenguaje de programación este dará un error

Comment: Saludos. En un `CASE`evalua primero si donde usas el (que refieres) `fechaVisitaADD` da 0; entonces ahí pones un valor acorde a la regla de negocio (puede ser devolver `NULL` o devolver `0`; o como lo manejes). Es solo que evalues el divisor no sea 0 antes de realizarse con este la operación.

Comment: ¿Y cual debiera ser el promedio cuando no tiene `fechaVisitaADD` para dividir?

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como está la consulta el único campo que actúa como denominador de las divisiones es `fechaVisitaADD` por lo que puedes añadir una condición en un `WHERE` para que realice el `SELECT` solo en el caso que este campo no sea nulo y no sea cero.

```
Select Count(fechavisitaadd) As planeadosvisita
     , Count(riesgoalto) As vriesgoalto
     , Convert(Decimal(10, 1), Convert(Decimal(10, 1), Count(riesgoalto)) / Count(fechavisitaadd) * 100) As vpromalto 
       --, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), COUNT(RIESGOALTO)) / COUNT(fechaVisitaADD) * 100)) AS VPROMALTO

     , Count(riesgomedio) As vriesgomedio
     , Convert(Decimal(10, 1), Convert(Decimal(10, 1), Count(riesgomedio)) / Count(fechavisitaadd) * 100) As vprommedio
       --, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), COUNT(RIESGOMEDIO)) / COUNT(fechaVisitaADD) * 100)) AS VPROMMEDIO
     , Count(fechavisitaadd) - (Count(riesgoalto) + Count(riesgomedio)) As vriesgobajo
     , Convert(Decimal(10, 1), Convert(Decimal(10, 1), Count(fechavisitaadd) - (Count(riesgoalto) + Count(riesgomedio))) / Count(fechavisitaadd) * 100) As vprombajo
--, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), (COUNT(fechaVisitaADD) - (COUNT(RIESGOALTO) + COUNT(RIESGOMEDIO)))) / (PLANEADOSVISITA) * 100)) AS VPROMBAJO
       From .......
WHERE ISNULL(fechaVisitaADD, 0) <> 0
```